# Is 35g/in^2 a good "rule" to use for upside down reflow surface tension?

Tags: pcb, soldering, assembly, reflow

I have one assembler that gave me their "rule" of 35g/in^2 for reflow parts falling off upside down or successfully hanging on.

Are there any sources that point to this being any more than their preference?

I have a 1" long pin header of 16 pins that is 42g/in^2 and another supplier wanting to make the same thing with larger pins I suspect because of more surface area. The first company says it will reflow just fine.

I've never had to use adhesive with an upside assembly, but if it's thick enough I suspect that would be an option.

Does anyone have a different calculation for this?

Comment: This is going to depend strongly on the exact formulation of solder in use; it will differ between SAC305, SAC358, 63/37, 62/36/2, SN100C, Sb5, Sn99.7.... There really isn't any one number you can use here, even if you don't consider the fact that there's more to it than just the pad area.